# how to read a .txt file and show it in a web page? (using express)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

I'm developing a server-side rendered website. The site is a collection of articles (files with .txt extension) loaded with a form that saves the information in a database and saves the file in a folder (text). The site has a read button that opens a bootstrap modal, where the content of the .txt file associated with that article should appear. Any solution? thank you

The server uses .ejs for the template

bootstrap modal code:

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="read-player" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                          <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                              <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle"> <%=article.title%> </h5>
                              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                              </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                             <!-- Content text file -->

                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Chiudi</button>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
```

[Text folder with articles text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpWBl.png)

[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRNFc.png)

Comment: It sounds like all you need to do is load the file and inject it into the webpage surrounded by &lt;pre> tags

Comment: Note: What you are doing is vulnerable to script injection. You should consider creating a Content-Security-Policy for the page.

Comment: @ControlAltDel ok, how do i get the file? I tried to do <% = article.id_text%> but nothing appears. Any advice for creating a content security policy? thank you

Comment: Is the file coming from the server or the client? If it's the server, you need to check out node.js's FS API. If it's from the client, you need an <input type="file"> on your page.

Comment: @ControlAltDel the file coming from server, I should get it from the public / text / path